# How to take rss feeds from "http://myname.disqus.com/latest.rss" to my django blog?

Tags: django, rss, disqus

I want to show latest 3 comments from disqus and link them to a post which they belong. I had some researches and they usually explain how to create rss feed but I want to take rss data. 
When I open this rss I see xml like this:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>

<title>unicrow - Latest Comments</title>
<link rel="http://api.friendfeed.com/2008/03#sup" href="http://disqus.com/sup/all.sup#forumcomments-e63e6ca0" type="application/json" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
<link>http://unicrowblog.disqus.com/</link>
<description/>
<atom:link href="http://unicrowblog.disqus.com/comments.rss" rel="self"/>
<language>en</language>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 01 Nov 2012 10:54:23 -0000</lastBuildDate>

<item>
<title>Re: http://box:8005/post/git-flow/</title>
<link>http://box:8005/post/git-flow/#comment-697865561</link>
<description>&lt;p>hjkgjfgtk&lt;/p></description>
<dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">kripton1</dc:creator>
<pubDate>Thu, 01 Nov 2012 10:54:23 -0000</pubDate>
</item>
...
</channel>
</rss>
```

I want to use this xml in my django project. How to take this xml rss feed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution. I did xml parser in python like that

```
file = urllib2.urlopen('http://unicrowblog.disqus.com/latest.rss')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    dom = parseString(data)
    lists = []

    for i in range(1,4):
        xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('description')[i].toxml()
        xmlData=xmlTag.replace('<description>&lt;p&gt;','').replace('&lt;/p&gt;</description>','')
        xmlDateTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('pubDate')[i].toxml()
        xmlDate=xmlDateTag.replace('<pubDate>','').replace('</pubDate>','')
        xmlLinkTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('link')[i+1].toxml()
        xmlLink=xmlLinkTag.replace('<link>','').replace('</link>','')

        data = {'xmlData':xmlData,'xmlDate':xmlDate,'xmlLink':xmlLink}
        lists.append(data)
```

I take 3 latest comment and I use it in template like that:

```
{% for list in lists %}
    <li>
       <span>{{list.xmlData|slice:":80"}}...</span>
       <span>→ <a href="{{list.xmlLink}}">Devamı</a></span>
       <span class="time">{{list.xmlDate}}</span>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification, I havent done this before, but I think studying [this link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries) can help. You could parse the xml and form a HttpResponse for your project. Hope this can lead you into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it automatically retrieves the data from Disqus and displays

```
<div id="recentcomments" class="dsq-widget"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://YOURBLOG.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=5&hide_avatars=1&avatar_size=50&excerpt_length=10"></script></div>
```

Do not forget to mention your blog name in place of ***YOURBLOG***.